# PHPのprinter_openでエラーが出ます

Tags: php

初めて質問させていただきます。
PHPの`printer_open`についてです。

以前Windows XPで動かしていたPHPのプログラムを、Windows 7で動かすための移行作業をしております。
XPではApache ver.1.3.29、PHP ver.4.3.9.9で動かしていました。
7にはApache ver.2.2.14、PHP ver.5.4.10をインストールし、ほとんどのプログラムは動いています。
ただ、印刷を行うプログラムで以下のようなエラーが出ます。

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function printer_open() in C:\Apache2.2\htdocs\～ on line 261

対象の行に書かれているプログラムが、以下になります。

```
$handle = printer_open("Canon LBP3310");
```

もちろん、対象のプリンターのドライバーはインストールしており、ネットワーク経由で印刷は可能な状態になっています。
また、`c\WINDOWS\system32\`に`php5ts.dll`、`c\php\ext\`に`php_printer.dll`は入れており、`php.ini`で「`extension=php_printer.dll`」部分の`;`は外しております。

原因に心当たりがある方がおりましたら、ご回答いただけますと幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: printer_open()がundefinedというエラーなのでphp.iniの設定かその他環境が原因だと思います。phpinfo();の結果に「printer」の項目はありますか？無ければphp_printer.dllが正常に読み込めてないです。